MYSQL variable to create query filter
I have a table with columns 'year', 'month' and 'price'. Created a variable from the year and month to create a date to be used to filter the table.
SELECT
@date_create := STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(`year`, '-', `month`, '-1'), '%Y-%m-%d'),`price`
FROM table
WHERE
@date_create >= '2023-05-01'

MYSQL returns 0 results but it shouldn't. What is wrong with the query?

You cannot use @date_create as a parameter because the @date_create on the left side is taken from a column in the table.

What is wrong with the query? @date_create in WHERE is a constant, not a value  which will be calculated in the output list. Its value is equal to those at the moment when the query execution starts (i.e. NULL in most cases). Hence none rows are returned because WHERE NULL >= '2023-05-01' is always FALSE.

I'm not sure if the @date_create user variable you define in the select clause would even be available in the where clause.  But you shouldn't be using this approach.  Consider the following query, which avoids the dynamic SQL:
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE year > 2023 OR (year = 2023 AND month >= 5);


Thanks! I am thinking too complicated :-)
